# I want to autoplay amp video only once

Tags: amp-html

I would like to autoplay the amp-video on my amp page but I want that to happen only once instead of playing it every time you scroll to the video. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet should be included as you're asking for code help.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. Here is the code
<amp-video width="720" height="405" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png" layout="responsive" controls autoplay>

Since autoplay attribute is present the video will be automatically played as soon as it becomes visible and I would like to play it once. Is that possible?

https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-video/?format=websites